# Accessing the name of the variable rather than its value

Tags: sass

I am trying to write a loop that will cycle through colors and condense the amount of code in my scss file. Here is a simple example of what I have:

```
$color1: blue;
$color2: red;
$color3: white;
$color4: black;

.color1-bg { background-color: $color1; }
.color2-bg { background-color: $color2; }

.color1-border { border-color: $color1; }
.color2-border { border-color: $color2; }
```

And so on.

I am looking for a way to write a loop so that when I use the variable to generate the class, it has the name of the variable rather than its value:

```
@each $color in $colour1, $colour2, $colour3, $colour4 {
    .#{$color}-bg { background-color: $color; }
    .#{$color}-border { border-color: $color; }
}
```

Comment: Your example seems to have gotten lost.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the output you desire?  Also, the example code does not seem entirely practical.

Comment: Basically, the client site has "themes" which they want to be color co-ordinated, and they also want to be able to select the colors for a list of colors in their style guide. I am basically letting them select from "color1, color2, color3" etc., and using the classes to display color swatches, and will use their choice as the class prefix.

Comment: I think you just forgot two `}` - check my answer

Comment: Fixed my example - see my comment below for why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't access the name of the variable directly, you'd have to store it as an additional value.

## Sass 3.2 and older (list of lists)

Sass doesn't have mappings yet, so the next best thing is a list of lists.

```
$color1: ('color1', blue);
$color2: ('color2', red);
$color3: ('color3', white);
$color4: ('color4', black);

@each $color in $color1, $color2, $color3, $color4 {
    $name: nth($color, 1);
    $value: nth($color, 2);
    .#{$name}-bg { background-color: $value; }
    .#{$name}-border { border-color: $value; }
}
```

## Sass 3.3 and newer (mappings)

Starting with 3.3, you have access to mappings.  It's functionally the same as the list of lists, but syntactically more concise.

```
$colors:
    ( 'color1': blue
    , 'color2': red
    , 'color3': white
    , 'color4': black
    );

@each $name, $value in $colors {
    .#{$name}-bg { background-color: $value; }
    .#{$name}-border { border-color: $value; }
}
```

## Alternately

Or if your color names are really "color1", "color2", etc., you can also just construct the name on the fly rather than specifying them explicitly:

```
$color1: blue;
$color2: red;
$color3: white;
$color4: black;

$num: 0;
@each $color in ($color1, $color2, $color3, $color4) {
    $num: $num + 1;
    .color#{$num}-bg { background-color: $color; }
    .color#{$num}-border { border-color: $color; }
}
```

Comment: The color names really are incremented.. no point in defining them, really. This is EXACTLY what I was looking for. Brilliant! Thanks @hopper!

Comment: You can make nested named lists by alternating separators between commas and spaces.
`$colorList:
    "red"    $red,
    "green"  $green
;`

Answer (score 3):

Ya, this is quite some time from the op, but thought, I'd add it anyway :)

This is what you are looking for with the least amount of repetition.
You can just add new colors to your $eric-holmes-colors array and recompile.

```
$eric-holmes-colors: "blue", "red", "white", "black";

@each $color in $eric-holmes-colors {
    .#{$color}-bg {
        background-color: #{$color};
    }
    .#{$color}-border {
        border-color: #{$color};
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice one. The accepted answer is more what I was looking for, as they were pre-existing colour variables. I also wanted the index to be part of the name (`.color1-bg`). But thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a comment on the previous answers. It's possible to combine both answers, which results in pretty elegant code (in my not-so-humble opinion).

I use Dutch color names, I do so on purpose  as to make clear we're not dealing with HTML color names.

```
$rood      : #e3004a;
$blauw     : #009ee0;

@each $color in ('rood', $rood), ('blauw', $blauw) {

    $name: nth($color, 1);
    $value: nth($color, 2);

    .#{$name} {
        a{
            background-color: $value;
        }                   
    }
}
```

CSS

```
.rood a { background-color: #e3004a; }

.blauw a { background-color: #009ee0; }
```

Comment: Side point, but I would avoid using the colour name when naming your variables.

Comment: I actually much prefer using the colour names as the variable. It makes your SASS files much more readable.

Comment: @Ideogram cool concept. I used indexes (colour1-5) so I only had to store the index in the database on a per-entry level (allowed the user to select colour for a post).

Answer (score 0):

According to the sass-reference your code should look like this, but i haven´t tried it myself.

```
@each $color in $color1, $color2, $color3, $color4 {
  .#{$color}-bg { background-color: $color;}
  .#{$color}-border { border-color: $color;}
}
```

http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#control_directives

Comment: The problem here is that `.#{$color}-bg` is translating into `.white-bg` rather than `.color1-bg`